# Get data from Parse server for offline usage

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to develop an android application while storing database on parse server. Everything works fine but problem is with application offlime usage. Is there any way i  can store data locally including log in details and fetch data from server only when updated. plz give me some suggestion examples would be better. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at SQLLite for Android. Not sure if keeping login information on the client is a good idea but you could do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Localdatastore.

1. in your android app enable it.

   ```
   Parse.Configuration config = new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
           .applicationId("XXXXXXXXXXX") 
           .clientKey("XXXXXXXXXXX")
           .server("https://api.serverused.com/")
           .enableLocalDataStore() // Acticate it here
           .build();

   Parse.initialize(config);  //
   ```
2. This is how to save the object or list of objects offline

   ```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(“GameScore");
       query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YE", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
       public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {

       // object will be your game score so save it offline
          object.pinAllInBackground();  
          } else {
       // something went wrong
       }
     }
   });
   ```
3. This is how to get your localdata

   ```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(“GameScore");
       query.fromLocalDatastore();
       query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YE", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
       public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {
       // object will be your game score
          } else {
       // something went wrong
       }
     }
   });
   ```

If you are saving a list of objects, generally used with findInBackground, you will need to use

```
ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(objects);
```

Hope this helps and check the docs [Parse LocalDataStore](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#local-datastore)